# How to export pandas dataframe containing strings with accented characters to a CSV file without getting any additional characters in the output file?

Tags: python-3.x, pandas, export-to-csv, diacritics, non-ascii-characters

I have been trying to export a pandas dataframe which has accented characters in few columns to csv.
When printed in the iPython notebook the string looks just fine.
 for example, the dataframe is as follows:

```
  col1 col2
1 001  Éxamplé
```

but when i'm exporting the dataframe to CSV using `df.to_csv` function using 'utf-8' encoding the output in CSV file looks as follows:

```
  col1 col2
1 001  Ã‰xamplÃ©
```

whereas the desired output is:

```
  col1 col2
1 001  Éxamplé
```

How can we do this without getting characters changed?

Comment: It's working fine in my system

Comment: Did you manage to do it?

Answer (score 1):

This should work in most cases.

```
data.to_csv("Data.csv", encoding="utf-8")
```

But its really hard to say what you need without knowing specifics. Is the text in foreign language? What software you're using to view the file after saving it? It might be because of that software and not the file itself.
Make sure to check out pythons standard encoding [here](https://docs.python.org/3/library/codecs.html#standard-encodings).

Comment: I'm using the same line of code as you have shared and I'm using MS Excel for viewing the files.

Comment: I tested quickly and for me it seems that excel is causing the problem.

Try opening the file with pandas. Does it look ok? 
If yes, then the problem is because of Excel. try this:
https://www.itg.ias.edu/content/how-import-csv-file-uses-utf-8-character-encoding-0

Cheers!

Comment: It looks okay with pandas. I can see that the string is exactly as I want in iPython NB. but when I'm opening the excel file it is getting altered. As per your suggestion I tried using 'utf8_decode()' function in excel but there is no such function available in Excel 2016. Thanks :)

Comment: Sorry I am not an excel expert :) perhaps this link will help? https://www.itg.ias.edu/content/how-import-csv-file-uses-utf-8-character-encoding-0

Answer (score 1):

```
df.to_csv(filename,encoding='utf-8-sig')
```

Try this mode it works for me.